# PickerView inside TableView implementation in Titanium

Tags: titanium-alloy, picker

I have created a PickerView inside the TableView, that is on tableViewRow. But I'm not able to access the full properties of the Picker.

For example I'm not able to set the TextHint for the the PickerView
I'm not able to fetch the selectedRow in the picker in index.js

here is my code in index.xml

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <!-- <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label> -->
    <TableView id="table">
        <TableViewSection>
             <TableViewRow>
                <TextField id="id_membership_number" width="Ti.UI.FILL" hintText="Membership Number"/>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
             <Picker id="id_picker" selectionIndicator="true" onChange="picker_method" value="Sector" selectionIndicator="true">
            <!-- On iOS, views can be added to picker rows -->
                    <PickerColumn id="column1">                
                        <PickerRow title="Real Estate"  id="id_picker_row">0</PickerRow>
                        <PickerRow title="Automobiles"  id="id_picker_row">1</PickerRow>
                        <PickerRow title="Others"  id="id_picker_row">2</PickerRow>
                    </PickerColumn>
            </Picker>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow title="Region"/>
            <TableViewRow title="Membership Type"/>
        </TableViewSection>
    </TableView>
    <Button id="id_member_search_btn" onClick="member_search_method"></Button>
</Window>
```

index.js

```
function picker_method(event){
    event=$.id_picker;
    Ti.API.info("User selected: " + event.getSelectedRow(0) + column.getSelectedRow(0));
}
```

On Console I get:

```
User selected: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <!-- <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label> -->
    <TableView id="table">
        <TableViewSection>
             <TableViewRow>
                <TextField id="id_membership_number" width="Ti.UI.FILL" hintText="Membership Number"/>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow>
             <Picker id="id_picker" selectionIndicator="true" onChange="picker_method" value="Sector" selectionIndicator="true">
             <!-- On iOS, views can be added to picker rows -->
                <PickerColumn id="column1">                
                    <PickerRow title="Real Estate"/>
                    <PickerRow title="Automobiles"/>
                    <PickerRow title="Others"/>
                </PickerColumn>
            </Picker>
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow title="Region"/>
            <TableViewRow title="Membership Type"/>
        </TableViewSection>
    </TableView>
    <Button id="id_member_search_btn" onClick="member_search_method"></Button>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

In your JS:

```
function picker_method(event){
    Ti.API.info("user selected   : "+event.selectedValue);
}
```

You should read the change event documentation for more info about what is passed to the onchange handler http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-event-change

Also, please note I removed the duplicate ID you had on the PickerRows, ID has to be unique.